# Django 2.1.1 'set' object is not reversible'set' object is

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

[This is basically the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmXAA.png)

**shops/urls**

```
#/shop/
from django.urls import path`enter code here
from . import views

app_name='shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.allProdCat, name='allProdCat'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>/', views.allProdCat, name='products_by_category'),
    path('<slug:c_slug>/<slug:product_slug>/', views.ProdCatDetail, name='ProdCatDetail'),
]
```

**shop/templates/shop/header**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<header>
    <center>
        <a href="{% url 'shop:allProdCat' %}"><img class ='zapp-logo' src="{% static 'img/zapp_banner.jpg' %}" alt="Logo "></a>
    </center>
</header>
```

Went through some searches, havent found any solutions. Anyone knows the problem?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from shop import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

**EDIT :**

**main/shop/templates/shop/base.html** ( header extends from)

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="{% block metadescription %}{% endblock %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/all.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        {% include 'shop/header.html' %}
        {% include 'shop/navbar.html' %}
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
        {% include 'shop/footer.html' %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main/urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**main/settings** (some parts)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop',
    'cart',
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shop', 'templates/'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cart', 'templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'shop.context_processor.menu_links'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Please show your main urls.py. Are you sure you are using a list (`[...]`) and not a set (`{...}`)?

Comment: Hey Daniel, edits made, not sure whats going on. This same error/ issue persists in all my hrefs that have a DTL that calls for a URL

Comment: You might need to show the other urls as well, for carts. As I say, the problem is that somewhere you are using a set instead of a list.

Comment: OH MY GOD DAN, I have embarrassed myself, you're right. My carts urls is indeed a set... thanks so much hahaha, i was stuck on this for the longest time